# How to encrypt a DBconnection string without aspnet_regiis.exe?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

I have a web.config file which already contains encrypted database entries for an existing application; the ones that are not in use are commented out.

I want to add a new connection string (for my database on localhost) so I can develop locally. The application requires that the connection string be encrypted.

From what I understand, it's necessary to use aspnet_regiis.exe to encrypt an entire file or entire section of a web.config file. However, I don't want to encrypt strings that have already been encrypted.

Originally, when I looked at the keys, it looked like simple Base64 encoding. As such, I tried converting my DBconnection string to Base64 using an online converter, but that didn't work correctly - the resulting connection string still gave me an error, and it was also much shorter than the other strings in the webconfig. This led me to believe that the DBconnection strings aren't just a simple Base64 conversion from the original string.

Question: How can I convert a single string to ASP.NET dbconnection encryption? Can aspnet_regiis.exe encrypt a single argument?

Sub-question: What form of encryption does ASP.NET use for its connection strings? It's encoded in Base64, but I don't think it's a straight conversion.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding - it is **not** encryption. I suggest reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx).

Comment: @Oded I know. Unfortunately, I believe there's encryption going on as well - I tried converting a string to raw Base64 format, which didn't work. The Base64 string I received was also much shorter than the other keys in the webconfig, leading me to believe that there was an intermediate encryption/conversion step.

Comment: There is no Base64 happening. It is RSA by default. Read the documents I linked.

Comment: @Oded Hope I'm not being annoying, but I'm not sure I understand -  the RSA key is represented in Base64 format. Wouldn't that be string -> encryption -> encoding?

Comment: The _key_ may be in Base64, not sure. But the cypher text is not.

Comment: @Oded Additionally, there's another similar question with the answer I seek. My previous SO search wasn't worded in a way to catch that question. I've flagged this one as a duplicate.